# Non-nullable instance field 'name' must be initialized

Tags: dart, constructor

getting error of Non-nullable instance with the constructor name "Bread" in Bread class. I have tried to correct my syntax from other Dart classes like Bakery class of mine. There is no error in the Bakery class Constructor Name. I can not understand where I am making a mistake.

```
import 'bread.dart';

class Bakery{
  Bakery(
      this.name,
      this.waitTime,
      this.distance,
      this.label,
      this.logoUrl,
      this.desc,
      this.score,
      this.menu,
      );
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  String distance;
  String label;
  String logoUrl;
  String desc;
  num score;
  Map<String, List<Bread>> menu;
}

class Bread{

  Bread(
      this.imgUrl,
      this.desc,
      this.waitTime,
      this.score,
      this.cal,
      this.price,
      this.quantity,
      this.ingredients,
      this.about,
      {this.highlight=false}
      );
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  String cal;
  num price;
  num quantity;
  List<Map<String, String>> ingredients;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
}
```

Comment: There is no `this.name,` in your `Bread` constructor.

Comment: oh i see, thank u...

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `this.name` in the constructor. (see line 3)

```dart
class Bread {
  Bread(
    this.name,
    this.imgUrl,
    this.desc,
    this.waitTime,
    this.score,
    this.cal,
    this.price,
    this.quantity,
    this.ingredients,
    this.about, {
    this.highlight = false,
  });
  String imgUrl;
  String desc;
  String name;
  String waitTime;
  num score;
  String cal;
  num price;
  num quantity;
  List<Map<String, String>> ingredients;
  String about;
  bool highlight;
}
```